# If a variable is defined in terms of another, can it reflect changes in the binding of the other?

Tags: javascript, variables

I have a variable whose value is partly defined in terms of another variable. I want to change the value of that variable so that the initial variable also changes. But this doesn’t happen. Look at the second line:

```js
var offset = 0;
var message = "the number is " + offset;
```

If I modify `offset`, then `message` doesn’t change:

```js
console.log(message); // This says "the number is 0".
offset += 20;         // `offset` is changed to `20`.
console.log(message); // The message is still "the number is 0".
```

`message`, in this case, would then be called a “reactive” variable.

Why doesn’t it work, and how would I solve it?

Comment: That's not how variables work in any language that I'm aware of.

Comment: it doesn't work because variables in JavaScript (as in most languages) use eager assignment rather than lazy assignment. To achieve what you want, you'd probably need to construct message as a function.

Comment: Not *defined*, built. You have a variable whose value is partly *built* with another variable. How to solve it? Build `message` again with the new value. And because it is annoying writing the same code over and over again, put it in a *(template)* function.

Comment: The same question for PHP: [PHP: Evaluating variable in string, and then changing value of variable](/q/11221360/4642212).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its just a simple assignment that when program flow reach it, concatenates `"the number is"` to *value of offset* & continues towards next lines to the end of program.

This is the nature of Javascript, The primitive types (Number, String, etc.) are passed by value. So changes in `offset` won't be reflected in `message`.

> The variable doesn't "hold" the object, it holds a reference. You can assign that reference to another variable, now both reference the same object. It's always pass by value (even when that value is a reference...).
>   There's no way to alter the value held by a variable passed as a parameter, which would be possible if JS supported passing by reference.[From Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language#answer-518069)

In order to have an always dependent value of message, you can define it as a function:

```js
var offset = 0;
var message = function(){
  return('the number is ' + offset);
}

console.log(message());   //this says 'the number is 0'

offset +=20;             //offset is changed to 20

console.log(message());  //this says 'the number is 20'
```

Comment: *"The primitive types (Number, String, etc.) are passed by value."* Careful with terminology here. "Pass by value" and "pass by reference" usually describe the relationship between **variables** (/parameters) . The actual "type" of the value the variable holds is irrelevant. You might be thinking of *value types* (primitive) and *reference types* (objects), but that has nothing to do with "pass by value". See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy .The quote is correct though.

Comment: Agreed, the answer isn’t quite correct. It’s not about data types. All variables are bound by value. For objects, the value just _is_ the reference. There isn’t an inherent difference between objects and primitives that is relevant to variable bindings.

Answer (score 2):

The expression `'the number is' + offset` is only evaluated once. It doesn't matter how many times you update `offset`, JavaScript does not keep track of any relation between `message` and `offset`, they are two separate variables.

As was suggested, you could use a function to represent the message instead of a variable.

```js
var offset = 0;

function message() {
    return 'the number is ' + offset;
}

console.log(message());  
offset += 20;             
console.log(message());
```

This way, the message gets recomputed each time.

Answer (score 2):

> Why doesn't it work

When you did `'the number is ' + offset`, the value of `offset` was read then and there to create a new value, the string `'the number is 20'`, which was assigned to `message`. The new value doesn't "know" how it was created and therefore cannot recompute itself. That's simply not how JavaScript works.

> I want to change the value of that variable so that the initial variable also changes.

That's not possible with *variables*. But you can use an *object* with a getter to achieve a similar effect:

```js
var obj = {
  offset: 0,
  get message() {
    return 'the number is ' + this.offset;
  },
};

console.log(obj.message);
obj.offset += 20;
console.log(obj.message);
```

(Note: the getter is not necessary you could also just create a normal method/function and call it as `obj.message()`)

Answer (score 1):

It shows up `0` in both cases, because while you are setting it, the `offset` value is 0 and that's the information which the `message` variable **will hold** until you change it's value.

```js
var offset = 0;
var message = 'the number is ' + offset;
console.log(message);  
offset += 20;             
console.log(message);
```

You have to reassign (refresh) the `offset` variable to the `message` variable to make the changes visible.

```js
var offset = 0;
var message = 'the number is ' + offset;
console.log(message);  
offset += 20;  
message = 'the number is ' + offset;
console.log(message);
```